# The Second and third ZIP of this simple script are nowhere to be found

Tags: linux, cron, zip

I'm having problem to understand why the second and third ZIP of the script below are nowhere to be found.

This script as been tested in a pre-production environment with the same file structure, using crontab. I have scheduled a run in production environment last night at 9PM, but I can't find the second and third ZIP.

If I look at the log file generated, I can clearly see that the files are been compressed and that the elapsed time between each ZIP is the approximate expected time to compress the content of those folders (18-20 min total).

Note that the /sites/Share_Drive/ is a shared drive mounted on multiple machine and could possibly not be physically installed in the same box, as far as I know, but most importantly it is configured the same way as our pre-production environment.

Any thought?

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG="/home/userX/script/run.log"

echo "Script Started - "`date` > $LOG

#Access the drive to make sure it is mounted. (If not it is mounted automatically when accessed)
echo "Opening Share Drive - "`date` >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
cd /sites/Share_Drive/
ls -lrt  >> $LOG
cd /home/userX/script/
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

echo "" >> $LOG

echo "Archiving /apps/AppNameWeb/ - "`date` >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
zip -vr /sites/Share_Drive/snapshot/AppNameWeb.zip /apps/AppNameWeb/ >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

echo "" >> $LOG

echo "Archiving /sites/Share_Drive/Content/ - "`date` >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
zip -vr /sites/Share_Drive/snapshot/Content.zip /sites/Share_Drive/Content/ >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

echo "" >> $LOG

echo "Archiving /sites/Share_Drive/AssettStore/ - "`date` >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
zip -vr /sites/Share_Drive/snapshot/AssettStore.zip /sites/Share_Drive/AssettStore/ >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

echo "Script Ended - "`date` >> $LOG
```

Comment: I wonder, what's the timeout on your automounter? Is it possible that the destination directory is getting unmounted while the second `zip` is running? If that is the case, your files might be created, but then hidden when the drive gets re-mounted. I seem to remember something like that happening to me once, but it was quite a while ago...

Comment: Use `exec &> $LOG` instead of redirecting every single line in your script. Additionally use `set -x` to debug the script in order to find the error.